# How to get from own survey data in csv to likert stacked bar chart?

Tags: r

Sorry for asking this,

but all the other questions and even the help and howto seem so much more advanced, that the 'simple' thing seems to go uncovered:

I have my own survey data. It is in Excel. My Likert like scale is coded 0-5

- 0 Not considered
- 1 Very Low
- 2 Low
- 3 Medium
- 4 High
- 5 Very High

I exported it to a CSV, Headers are the Questions, below each line represents a respondent.

```
Q1;Q2;Q3;Q4 
0;3;3;2
1;0;3;3
2;0;5;4
```

That should be straightforward, right?

I import it into a dataset

```
DFG <- read.csv("export.csv", headers = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

I can see the dataset fine with print (DFG), the headers look OK, too. But that's how far I got. Likert complains about

```
All items (columns) must have the same number of levels
items parameter contains non-factors. Will convert to factors
```

All columns have the same amount of data, 58 sets, there are no unanswered items.

I'm not even thinking about adding Grouping, I am so far away from a bar-chart, I can't even get this to work. What am I missing?

Step 2:

After applying Heather's solution to my initial problem with

```
DFG <- lapply(DFG, factor, levels = 0:5)
```

apparently, now R is aware of Levels (which it wasn't before) and I get a print(DFG) result of

```
$H1.1..founders..education
[1] 3 4 2 2 5 4 4 3 3 4 3 1 2 2 4 4 4 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 2 3 4 3 2 3 4 5
[36] 2 1 2 3 3 5 5 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 0 4 2 4 2 0
Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5

$H1.2..founders..past.professional.experience
[1] 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 3 3 5 5 3 2 5 4 5 5 4 4 4 3 5 4 4 3 4 3 3 5 5 4 2 4 4 5
[36] 3 5 4 4 4 5 5 4 4 5 4 3 4 5 4 5 4 3 4 3 5 5 4
Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

(shortened)

And if I change that to

```
 DFG <- lapply(DFG, ordered, levels = 0:5)
```

I can run the net_stacked() script against it. Yay, happy! THANKS.

Comment: type `dput(head(DFG)` and add the result to your question

Comment: Welcome to SO.  There are at least two packages for Likert plots.  Please show the code you are using to draw them (as well as some sample data).

Comment: Also, practise using factors for categorical variables.  Rather than having integer values (0 to 5), you can have readable category labels ("Not considered", etc.) with factors.

Comment: Im using Bryer's Likert module. likert(DFG) already fails for me. So it's rather the getting the basics together, than actual plotting issues.

Comment: And thanks for the hint with the category labels. It makes sense to me now. It was juts the coding I got out of the survey tool...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read the data in with `read.csv` the columns are read in as numeric variables (as you have not specified otherwise).

The function you are using requires the columns to be factors - as they are not, it attempts to convert them to factors. The problem is that it does not know that the possible levels are 0-5 for each item. Therefore each column is converted to a factor with only the observed levels and as the full set of levels is not observed for each item, you get an error because the levels are not the same.

To fix this, convert the variables to factors yourself:

```
DFG <- lapply(DFG, factor, levels = 0:5)
```

Comment: Thanks for hanging in there with me. After your conversion, print(DFG) shows sth like this:

    $H1.1..founders..education
    [1] 3 4 2 2 5 4 4 3 3 4 3 1 2 2 4 4 4 3 3 4 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 2 3 4 3 2 3 4 5
    [36] 2 1 2 3 3 5 5 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 0 4 2 4 2 0
    Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5

    $H1.2..founders..past.professional.experience
    [1] 5 5 5 4 5 5 5 3 3 5 5 3 2 5 4 5 5 4 4 4 3 5 4 4 3 4 3 3 5 5 4 2 4 4 5
    [36] 3 5 4 4 4 5 5 4 4 5 4 3 4 5 4 5 4 3 4 3 5 5 4
    Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5

likert still does not like it, wrong number of dimensions.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646659/likert-in-r-with-unequal-number-of-factor-levels

Comment: This solution assumes the raw data are values in the set 0, 1, ..., 5. I will post an answer to your specific question.